# Can't show surface chart with Plotly, Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, plotly, angular12

im tryng to show a 3d model with Plotly (https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md), but the chart doesn't appear.

componente.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-componente',
  templateUrl: './componente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componente.component.css']
})
export class ComponenteComponent{
  
  getData() {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<25;i++)
        arr.push(Array(25).fill(undefined).map(() => Math.random()))
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  } 
  data: any[] = this.getData();

  public graph = {
    z: this.data,
    type: 'surface',
    layout: {autosize: true, title: 'Modelo 3d'}
  };

}
```

componente.component.html

```
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.z" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>
```

[image: This is what is showing now]
This is what is showing now

And should be something like this:
[image: And should be something like this]

I've trying to make it work on angular all day but im not good enough :/ any help will be amazing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it this way:

```
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js-dist-min';

getData() {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<40;i++)
        arr.push(Array(40).fill(undefined).map(() => Math.random() * 256))
    //console.log(arr);
    arr.push({type: 'scatter3d'});
    return arr;
  }

testButton () {
    this.getModelo3d();
    PlotlyJS.newPlot('chart', [{
      z: this.getData(),
      type: 'surface'
    }]);
  }
```

in html

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to the one you faced.

In my case, the problem was caused by the wrong module being imported.

I used Vue and installed it from the Vue-CLI, but I installed a module with a similar and another name.
Therefore, although surface and heatmap can be set, it is not supported, so it was processed as a line graph.

My import statement is:
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js-basic-dist';

According to the Github Readme, it's "plotly.js-dist-min".

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js#load-as-a-node-module

Answer (score 0):

I had the same goal, to render a 3d surface plot in Angular using Plotly, so I found your post. Thank you for the nudge in the right direction.

I came up with an alternative solution to why it was not rendering correctly with your original code, so thought I would post here for others.

Looks to me like the Plotly library is looking for an object that has both the **data**, and the **chart type** in the same object. Your binding from the plotly-plot UI element to the data is "too deep" and was missing the type property with value "surface".

With these changes, it renders fine for me:

```js
getData() {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<25;i++)
        arr.push(Array(25).fill(undefined).map(() => Math.random()))
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  } 
  data: any[] = this.getData();

  public graph = {
    data: [
      {
        z: this.getData(),
        type: 'surface'
      }
    ],
    layout: {autosize: true, title: 'Modelo 3d'}
  };
```

and the view...

```html
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>
```